# Jquery override data object before sending to the server globally in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm sending all my requests to the server using

```
$.ajax()
```

and what I want to do is to  globally add a `_csrf` token to all these requests before sending to the server.

I'm looking in to the function is jquery `beforesend()`, but I do not know how to declare this function for all the ajax requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

`beforeSend()` is a local event, if you want to bind to send for all ajax requests, you can use `ajaxSend()` which is fired on `document` for all ajax requests.

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    //add your token
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function( event, jqxhr, settings ) {
    console.log(setting.data); //get the data from settings and update it
});
```

Comment: Ok. Cool. but where is my data object when I catch this event ?? How can I update my data object before sending ??

Comment: Woop woop. Thanks @artm. So you do not have to return the data or anything right ??

Comment: @AndreFrexio Just modifying the data should be enough. i.e. `settings.data += 'token';`

Answer (score 0):

You want to set a default via [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) .

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: This is better. Thanks. My ideal scenario is where I will be encrypting all my data before sending using SJCL. Is it possible to manipulate the data object here ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using **$.ajaxPrefilter**, which contrary to $.ajaxSetup is not overridden by individual $.ajax calls from all over you project:

(It uses [jQuery Unserialize](https://plugins.jquery.com/unserialize/) plugin)

```
csrfData[csrfTokenName] = csrfToken;

$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    // Enhance data only on POST requests
    if (originalOptions.type.toUpperCase() === 'POST'
        || options.type.toUpperCase() === 'POST'
    ) {
        var originalData = $.unserialize(originalOptions.data);
        var enhancedData = $.extend(originalData, csrfData);
        options.data = $.param(enhancedData);
    }
});
```